# Finding the limit using sandwich theorem

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I have a limit from the integral $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\int_1^{a^n}\dfrac{u^{1/n}du}{(1+u)u}, \qquad a>1.$$
My teacher wants that I solve this equation using sandwich theorem. So it means, that I should find  $n_0$ and a sequence of function and $f_n, \quad g_n$ such that for all $n>n_0$ the following holds
$$f_n(u)\leq \dfrac{u^{1/n}1_{(1;a^n)}(u)}{(1+u)u}\leq g_n(u), \qquad u>1,$$

and $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\int_1^{+\infty}f_n(u)du=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\int_1^{+\infty}g_n(u)du=\ln2,$$
where $\quad 1_A(u)$ - indicator function.

Obviously, the sequence of function $f_n(u)=\dfrac{1}{u(1+u)}.$ I can not find the upper limiting sequence of function $g_n$, from wich the integral and the limit would be easy to find do not using dominated convergence theorem and other theorems. Some ideas or hints?!

Comment: Well, *in fact* your function $\,g\,$ is a **lower** bound, as $\,\sqrt[n] u\ge 1\;\;\forall\,u\ge 1\;$ ...

Comment: To apply sandwich you don't need to have inequalities between the integrands. All you need are bounds for what is inside the limit. By constructing that $g$ that you have you are actually giving a bound of the form $\int g$ to the integral inside the limit. Try finding the other bound, but not necessarily of the form $\int f$.

Comment: I've succeeded, imo, to bound the limit between $\,\log 2\,$ from the left and $\,1\,$ from the right...

Comment: If you could find f and g with the properties you give, you would have a proof that, for all $n$, $\int_1^{\infty}{u^{1/n}\over(1+u)u}=\log2$, which is more than you are asked to prove, so I think you have to allow $f$ and $g$ to depend on $n$.

Comment: @Gerry Myersen, good remark. I will try to reformulate my question